# TextBox - Identify Whether Data Entered is by the user

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

We are using a TextBox to display data received from the IO syetem. If the user enters some data on the text box, the value will be written to the IO system.

We are using OnTextChanged event to write the data entered by the user to the IO system.

The problem is that we get this event when we update the value received from the IO system to the text box (from the code).

Is it possible to know whether the value of the TextBox is changed by the user or by using the code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will fit your situation or not, but you can try with `KeyUp` or `KeyDown` event instead. The event will only be raised if user type something to TextBox and not raised if the text changed by code. `KeyUp` event raised after `TextChanged` so you'll have the newly typed text ready in TextBox. And `KeyDown` raised before `TextChanged` so you'll need to append current text in TextBox with the character/key being pressed. The downside of using `KeyUp`/`KeyDown` is that you won't get notified if user input the text by copy/cut-paste using context menu (right click > paste). The workaround is to disable default context menu as follow  (or via style) :

```
<TextBox ContextMenu="{x:Null}"/>
```

User still can do cut/copy/paste using keyboard shortcuts, and your program will get notified as some keyboard keys being pressed.

Hope this idea suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As I am not sure exactly what you are after so I will give you two solutions.

**Solution 1: Binding using MVVM.**

Instead of picking up on the OnTextChanged event, bind the TextBox to a property on your viewmodel. This will update the text via the Property. When updating from code, call a method to update the backing field. The ViewModel looks like

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return text; }
        set
        {
            if (value != text)
            {
                text = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
                Debug.WriteLine("Binding Example - Keyboard entry");
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddText(string extraText)
    {
        this.text += extraText;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("Text");
        Debug.WriteLine("Binding Example - Code entry");
    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Note that even though I am updating the backing field in the AddText method, I still call the OnPropertyChange to update the binding to the TextBox. The xaml for the TextBox would be

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

The UpdateSourceTrigger is important if you are looking to save as you type.

Although this is my preferred solution, massive amounts of text may cause a performance problem.

**Scenario 2: OnTextChanged**

You are already handling one event, handle all the relevant keyboard events (probably only Keydown). Your TextBox Xaml would be

```
<TextBox x:Name="EntryControl" PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyUp" KeyDown="UIElement_OnKeyDown" KeyUp="UIElement_OnKeyUp" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" />
```

If each event output its name to the output window, you would get the events in the following order

- UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown
- UIElement_OnKeyDown
- TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged
- UIElement_OnPreviewKeyUp
- UIElement_OnKeyUp

By setting a boolean value in the OnKeyDown event and checking for it in the OnTextChanged event, you could test for keyboard input.

NOTE: When holding down a key, you will get multiple KeyDown events to a single KeyUp events. The order the events are fired in are

-UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown
-UIElement_OnKeyDown
-TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged
-UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown
-UIElement_OnKeyDown
-TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged
-UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown
-UIElement_OnKeyDown
-TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged
-UIElement_OnPreviewKeyUp
-UIElement_OnKeyUp

So the solution will still hold up.

**Testing the solutions out**

If you are looking to try the 2 scenarios in a sample app, the xaml for my example is

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._20949513.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ViewModel}"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DockPanel>
            <Button Content="Add Text" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="BindingButton_OnClick" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button Content="Add Text" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Click="EventButton_OnClick" />
            <TextBox x:Name="EntryControl" PreviewKeyDown="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown" PreviewKeyUp="UIElement_OnPreviewKeyUp" KeyDown="UIElement_OnKeyDown" KeyUp="UIElement_OnKeyUp" TextChanged="TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged" />
        </DockPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the code behind is

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new MyViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MyViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    private void BindingButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { ViewModel.AddText("More Text"); }


    private bool keyboardPressed;

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { DisplayEvent(); }

    private void UIElement_OnPreviewKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { DisplayEvent(); }

    private void UIElement_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayEvent();
        keyboardPressed = true;
    }

    private void UIElement_OnKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) { DisplayEvent(); }

    private void TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (keyboardPressed)
            {
                DisplayEvent("TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged from Keyboard");
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayEvent("TextBoxBase_OnTextChanged from Code");
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            keyboardPressed = false;
        }
    }

    private void DisplayEvent([CallerMemberName] string caller = null) { Debug.WriteLine(caller); }

    private void EventButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) { EntryControl.Text += "More Text"; }
}
```

The ViewModel is shown in full at the start of the answer.

*Proper exception handling has been excluded for brevity.*

I hope this helps.